# I made a heads/tails script in perl and I want it to run more than once

Tags: perl, loops, scripting

i know there is a simple one-liner or command that will let it run over and over until i kill it, can someone show me?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Please type in either heads or tails: ";
$answer = <STDIN>;
chomp $answer;
while ( $answer ne "heads" and $answer ne "tails" ) {
    print "I asked you to type heads or tails. Please do so: ";
    $answer = <STDIN>;
    chomp $answer;
}
print "Thanks. You chose $answer.\n";
print "Hit enter key to continue: ";
$_ = <STDIN>;
if ( $answer eq "heads" ) {
    print "HEADS! you WON!\n";
} else {
    print "TAILS?! you lost. Try again!\n";
}
```

Is the code. I want it to ask again and again after the initial run

Comment: Can you elaborate?  You want it to run over and over on the same file?  Is it to determine whether new data has been appended?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";


print "Please type in either heads or tails: ";


$answer = <STDIN>;
chomp $answer;

while ( $answer ne "heads" and $answer ne "tails" ) {
        print "I asked you to type heads or tails. Please do so: ";
        $answer = <STDIN>;
        chomp $answer;
}

print "Thanks. You chose $answer.\n";
print "Hit enter key to continue: ";


$_ = <STDIN>;

if ( $answer eq "heads" ) {
        print "HEADS! you WON!\n";
} else {
        print "TAILS?! you lost. Try again!\n";
}


is the code, i want it to ask again and again after the initial run

Comment: @matth0x: Please EDIT your post and put the code there, then delete your comment.

Comment: Why are you printing a Content-Type header and then prompting for user input?  CGI scripts can't ask for input like that, and there's no point in printing a Content-Type header from a command-line script.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the main portion of the code in a while loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
while (1) {
    print "Please type in either heads or tails: ";
    $answer = <STDIN>;
    chomp $answer;
    while ( $answer ne "heads" and $answer ne "tails" ) { 
        print "I asked you to type heads or tails. Please do so: ";
        $answer = <STDIN>;
        chomp $answer;
    }   
    print "Thanks. You chose $answer.\n";
    print "Hit enter key to continue: ";
    $_ = <STDIN>;
    if ( $answer eq "heads" ) { 
        print "HEADS! you WON!\n";
    } else {
        print "TAILS?! you lost. Try again!\n";
    }   
}
```

Comment: and if you put `print "play again?"; chomp(my $again = <>); last if $again =~ /no/i;` just above the last brace, now you can gracefully exit.

Answer (score 1):

a lot of assumptions here, but a "one-liner or command" from a bash shell can be done with:

```
$ while true; do perl yourscript.pl; done
```

Answer (score 1):

kbenson is correct that you can surround your code in an infinite loop. A slightly more elegant way of doing this is to make a function which plays one round, then make an infinite loop around that function call. I use a few more tricks here, some of which may be new to you, if you don't understand something, please ask. Also I agree with cjm, I'm not sure why the content type is there so I left it out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (1) {
  play_round();
  print "Would you like to play again?: ";
  my $answer = <STDIN>;
  if ($answer =~ /no/i) {
    print "Thanks for playing!\n";
    last; #last ends the loop, since thats the last thing exit would work too
  }
}

sub play_round {
    print "Please type in either heads or tails: ";
    my $answer = <STDIN>;
    chomp $answer;
    while ( $answer ne "heads" and $answer ne "tails" ) { 
        print "I asked you to type heads or tails. Please do so: ";
        $answer = <STDIN>;
        chomp $answer;
    }   
    print "Thanks. You chose $answer. Now I'll flip.\n";

    sleep 1;

    my @coin = ('heads', 'tails');
    my $side = $coin[int rand(2)];

    print "And its ... $side! ";
    if ( $answer eq $side ) { 
        print "You WON!\n";
    } else {
        print "Sorry, you lost. Try again!\n";
    }   
}
```